# mapping arraylist object to dropdown(s:select) in struts 2

Tags: struts2

I have an arraylist of string **private ArrayList strarray = new ArrayList();** .   I have to map this String arraylist to dropdown(s:select).  give me the syntax for s:select tag to display strarray as dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/select.html)?

Anyway:

```
<s:select list="strarray" name="mystr" />
```